# Output non-ascii characters through wall command

Tags: unicode, wall

Using Linux Slackware 14.2, KDE. I created a script in Linux with Russian text that I want to output through wall:

```
#!/bin/bash
wall <<< 'Сообщение'
```

Instead of text I see the characters codes:

```
\320\241\320\276\320\276\320\261\321\211\320\265\320\275\320\270\320\265
```

I added to ~/.bashrc:

```
locale=C_UTF8
```

Then did:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

But it didn't work. How to fix this?

Comment: Could you find a solution to that problem? I'm facing the same issue and cannot really solve it.

Comment: @StevenThiel No, but we can ask at linuxquestions.